# Sails.js - use login instead of id for REST api

Tags: node.js, rest, sails.js

I'm using Sails.js framework, and I have `User` model with `login` field.

I also have `User` controller that allows me to send request like

```
http://localhost:1337/user/:id
```

And it returns given user data. However I'd prefer to use user login instead of user id so I could use `/user/mylogin` instead of `/user/564a0aacecf0e8fb20c38a4e`. Is there any way to do it without creating routes myself (I like how sails handle all default routes including relations like `/user/:id/comments` and I dont want to rebuild all of those just to use login instead of id)

Answer (score 1):

You could do /user?login=username. This is handled by sails's blueprint api: http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/blueprint-api/find-where

Comment: thats not reallt REST like

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it you can have it. But you have to get your hands a bit dirty. There are a few possibe ways. But I am pointing you out the easiest way seemed to me.

1. Add a route like following in your `config/routes.js`.

   ```
   '/user/:myLogin': {
       controller: 'user',
       action:'getUserByUserLogin'
   }
   ```
2. Add an action named `getUserByUserLogin` in your
   `api/controller/UserController.js`. You can access the `myLogin`
   value from request object from the controller action with
   `req.param("myLogin")`.

   ```
   module.exports = {
       getUserByUserLogin: function(req, res){
           var myLogin = req.param("myLogin");
           /* Do whatever you want */
       }
   };
   ```

Comment: In question I said I dont want to re-build it myself. It was not point of question ;)

Comment: Poor me, I couldn't get you -_- Anyway in this way you are not rebuilding it yourself I guess.

Comment: I do. Default system have it all already, including relations like /user/mylogin/posts/post-name/comments etc.